# Refresh AWS API Gateway Authorization Policy

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, oauth, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to refresh/delete an authorization policy for a single token. When a new user is given access to my API I would like them to have instant access without waiting for the cache TTL to pass.

Answer (score 0):

When you grant access to a new user, you can flush the cached policies of one stage with an API call.

see. [API-Gateway docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#flushStageAuthorizersCache-property)

```
var params = {
  restApiId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  stageName: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
apigateway.flushStageAuthorizersCache(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```